# How to run batch file in background with windows 10 startup?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

Can someone guide me on how to start bat file with windows startup

(even if the user is not logged on)
and how to run it in background

(the bat file should not be visible in taskbar)?

I have a .bat file and I have placed it in startup folder (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ==>`shellstartup`) so this way it is starting even without the user logging in but I want to know how to hide it from appearing in the taskbar.

Comment: *so this way it is starting even without the user logging in* it runs only when a user logs in.